# Python: for a long string where a certain word is repeated, how to identify the first occurrence of the word after a unique word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, extract, slice

I have a large file that is made up of many blocks of data. For example, two blocks of data would look like:

```
name1   1234567           comment                           
property1 = 1234567.98765 property2 = 1234567.98765
property3 = 1234567.98765
final

name2   1234568           comment                           
property1 = 987654.321 property2 = 9876543.0
property3 = 1234567.98765
final
...
```

**Problem**.
I have code to modify one block of data. However, the code results in a string (`updated_string`) that contains ALL data blocks in the file (the modified data block and all other unmodified data blocks).

**Goal**.
I only want the modified data block in `updated_string` and then I want to put only `updated_string` in an external file and leave all other data blocks in the file unmodified.

So far I have figured out from previous posts here how to delete everything from `updated_string` that comes before the modified data block.  For example, if the second data block has been modified, I would do:

```
mystring = "name2"
begin = string.find(mystring)
string[:begin]
```

However, I am not able to delete everything after the "`final`" in the data block I want.  I know I can do

```
mystring2 = "final"
stop = string.find(mystring2)
string[stop:]
```

but it doesn't identify the particular data block I want.  Can anyone please suggest how I might look for the first "final" after `name2` so that I can get a string made up of only the data block I want?

Comment: If you remove everything before this block, wouldn't first `"final"` be from the block you are interested in?

Comment: Is regex a requirement? Just to be clear you don't want to modify the original file at all right? Since you know the two landmarks you are interested in, I would read and discard rows until I found the first then read and save rows until I found the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, but assuming you want to find the block between `name2` and the first `final` that follows it, just adapting your current logic should work:

```
mystring = "name2"
begin = string.find(mystring)
string = string[begin:]         # we drop all before mystring

mystring2 = "final"
stop = string.find(mystring2)   # now we find the stop in the new string
string = string[:stop+len(mystring2)]
```

Or, better, use the `start` parameter of [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
mystring = "name2"
begin = string.find(mystring)

mystring2 = "final"
# now we only search the stop word after
# the position of the start word (+ its length)
stop = string.find(mystring2, begin+len(mystring))

out = string[begin:stop+len(mystring2)]
```

Output:

```
name2   1234568           comment                           
property1 = 987654.321 property2 = 9876543.0
property3 = 1234567.98765
final
```

Comment: yes, I now realize I wasn't clear, so thank you for figuring out what I wanted to do!